Our Azure DevOps pipeline deploys to development but fails in production due to restricted access
Our Azure DevOps pipeline deploys to development but fails in production due to restricted access in a separate subscription. How would you configure the pipeline to deploy successfully to production while handling these access restrictions?
I attempted to configure the Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy to production using the existing settings from the development environment, without considering the access restrictions of the separate subscription.
I expected the deployment to work seamlessly across both environments, assuming the same configuration would apply to production. However, due to restricted access in the production subscription, the deployment failed.

Deploy what exactly and how? Please provide more details, your question is quite vague. Are you using service connections for Azure subscriptions?

It depends what authentication method you are using to "deploy". More detail is needed to actually answer here.
Are you talking about infrastructure deployment or application deployment. In either case the most likely issue is that whatever authentication solution you are using to "deploy" such as a service principle, most likely only has the correct role/permissions in the scope of you development environment. Which again I can only assume and guess based on the lack of information would be in a separate subscription to your production one.
Make sure that whatever authentication method you are using has the correct roles to perform the desired actions within the correct scope.
